# OpenCV keeps "uninstalling" itself (Linux)

Tags: linux, opencv

Really annoying issue here. On Linux Mint OS. Every so often, I'll get this error when running OpenCV code:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/ravi/Desktop/opencv/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/highgui/window.cpp, line 180
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what(): /home/ravi/Desktop/opencv/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/highgui/window.cpp:180: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow
```

The way to fix this, I've found, it to do the following:

```
cd OpenCV/
cd build/
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
<restart computer>
```

Then I'll come back, start running my OpenCV code again, and it'll be fine. But then a few hours later, or possibly between turning cpu on/off, I'll be back to the same stupid error!

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here and how I can prevent this? It's frustrating as hell.

Comment: Now what on Earth can cause this? o.O

Comment: Just happened again. Ran my OpenCV project, worked. Changed some .cpp code, `make` in project directory, now not working again =(

Comment: Any chance your makefile is doing something freaky to the libraries? e.g. the `make clean` rule might be doing `rm /usr/local/lib/<some_opencv_shared_object>.so`?

Comment: Found something that sounds very similar: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=280361

Comment: Wait, I may have solved it: `ls /dev/vid*` - I've noticed that my webcam sometimes likes to switch between being in video1 and video2! Will update if this seems to solve everything. However I'd be curious as to why this ever happens (the switching of video1/2)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was solved by paying attention to where my USB camera was actually located in /dev/. Giving a faulty path to the get video source functions causes this type of error; restarting my computer occasionally shifted which /dev/video# my device was attached to.

Please do `ls /dev/vid*` to find out if you're using the right video source!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a general critical error in the program code. Is there a specific task that is done when the error occurs?  You might want to use strace to get the output of the program as it runs or enable application memory dumps for the user you are running the process as.  This would be passed to the developer for debugging and inspection.